# Present full screen view on tap on list entry in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to accomplish what I thought was a relatively simple thing, which is to have a view show fullscreen when you tap on an item in a list.
The code shown here works more or less.  However, I have to tap exactly on the text. Tapping the free area does not trigger the onTap event.

Sample code:

```swift
struct ItemListView: View {
    var items: [Item]
    var titel: String
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            ItemListCell(item: item)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedItem = item
                }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(titel)
        .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedItem, onDismiss: nil) { item in
            ItemDetailView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemListCell: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(item.id))
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(item.id))
        Text(item.name)
        Button {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            Label("Close", systemImage: "xmark.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

I also looked at the "Supporting Selection in Lists" chapter in the documentation, but that only works when the list is in edit mode.

Is there a swiftUI equivalent of UIKit's `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the frame of the content is taking up the whole cell. I do this in the sample below by using `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)`.

Then, add a `contentShape` modifier sot that SwiftUI knows to consider the entire shape to be the content -- otherwise, it tends to ignore the whitespace.

```
struct ItemListCell: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.id)
            Text(item.name)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .border(Color.green) //just for debugging to show the frame
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use `Button` instead of `onTapGesture`, you basically get this all for free:

```
List(items) { item in
    Button(action: {
        selectedItem = item
    }) {
        ItemListCell(item: item)
    }
}
```

Lastly, no, there is no direct equivalent of `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

Comment: A hint to the solution with the button. The text is then displayed in the Accent color.

Comment: You can use `.foregroundColor(.primary)` to change the color of the text in the button or `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` on platforms where that is affected.